# Array or object in Javascript eval?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, eval, math.js

I am working on a code optimization where I have several rows (~500-1000) of data with at least 300 columns.
The data is stored as an array of objects:

```
data = [
  {col1: 1, col2: 2, col3: null, col4: 1.3, col5:undefined, col6: 2, ....},
  {col1: 3, col2: 4, col3: 3, col4: 1.1, col5:8, col6: 2, ....},
  .
  .
  .
  {col1: 1.1, col2: 1.2, col3: 7, col4: 3, col5:4, col6: 2, ....}
]
```

Then I have another array of objects named calculators, these are user-defined calculations. These calculations can have another calculated variable like 2nd object in the following array.
So I need to maintain the order.

```
calculators = [
  {formula:'col1 + sin(col2)', order:0, colname: 'calc1'}
  {formula:'calc1 * col6', order:1, colname: 'calc2'}
  .
  .
  .
  {formula: 'any random calculation', order:n, colname:'RandomName'}
]
```

my current code-flow is,

- Extraction of dependent columns from calculators, like col1 and col2
  for calc1 and col6 from calc2.
  `dependentCols = [col1, col2, col6]`
- Looping through the data array with nested for loops for calculators and columns and setting the value in parser for each
  dependent column. `parser.set(column, row[column]);`
- Then formula evaluation and appending that value to the dararow.

The original code I have includes some other stuff to handle sub-columns, units, and other stuff. That's why instead of pasting the original code, here is the rough draft.

```
const parser = math.parser();
data = _.map(data, row=>{
    row = {...row};
    _.forEach(calculators, (calculator)=>{
      _.forEach(dependentCols, col=>{
            // cannot add the whole row as it is because of the sub-column stuff.
            parser.set(col, row[col]);
        });
        try {
          const value = parser.eval(calculator.formula);
          row[colname] = value;
        } catch (exception) {
          console.warn(parser, exception, calculator.colname);
        }
      }
    });
    return row;
  });
}
```

The original code is definitely working (for a year). Its just very slow, with 450 rows and 20 calculations its taking upto 12 seconds.
So instead of going row by row and effectively cell by cell I am thinking about passing the whole column at the same time to the eval function. But I couldn't find any supporting documentation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please do some profiling to find out what part of the code is that slow.

Comment: Does math.js have an API to parse a formula just once, then evaluate it with multiple different inputs?

Comment: The parser.eval part is the most expensive part here. And in the above case, I am reevaluating the same, with different values, for 450 times.

Comment: Yes, it does have that functionality, but I am not finding any good example which I can use here. But your question does give me an idea. Let me explore that. If it works I will update the post.